# iOS app versioning

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

In iOS, what's the difference between:

Bundle versions string, short AND Bundle version?

What to update when building a new release and when ?

[image]

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281085/whats-the-difference-between-version-number-in-itunes-connect-bundle-versio/7281246#7281246

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Bundle version is the internal version number of your app.

Short version string is the publically visible version of your app.

So for example, if you iterate your version number every time you do an internal build for your beta testers (or whatever), your bundle version might be 2.0.0.12345b7, but you don't want the public to see that, so you set your short version string to 2.0.

Short version string seems to be optional, so if you leave it blank then the bundle version is what people will see (i.e. that's what will be displayed on the App Store).

If you don't have a short version string, then the same rules apply to your bundle ID (basically the public app version has this restriction and the private app version doesn't).

There's a more detailed answer here:

[What's the difference between "version number" in itunes connect, "bundle version", "bundle version string" in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281085/whats-the-difference-between-version-number-in-itunes-connect-bundle-versio)

Comment: The [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html) specify `CFBundleVersion` as 'This value is a monotonically increased string, comprised of one or more period-separated integers'. Wouldn't this preclude setting it to `2.0.0.12345b7` per your answer?

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html

From docs..

**Bundle version is the one that must be in the info .plist and that's the one you should update every new version**..Bundle versions string, short is not must but is given although i didn't understood its use..