# Getting "error itms 9000 invalid image path" error while submitting app through application loader

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode5, app-store-connect, xcode4.6

I have created the xcarchive file from xcode 4.6. In xcode 4.6, we need to add only 4 sizes of app icon files. But I had added 3 extra app icon files in the xcode 4.6 to support ios 7. But when I submit the app, I am getting below error continuously.

> Apple's web service operation was not successful
>
> Unable to authenticate the package: 580659297.itmsp
>
> ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleVersion [042.3.1.0.b014] in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list of non-negative integers."
>
> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons'

[image]

Comment: The first error estates you have a problem with your CFBundleVersion, which is true. It is: 042.3.1.0.**b**014 but it should not contain any number (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281085/whats-the-difference-between-version-number-in-itunes-connect-bundle-versio). You should solve that and then see if the other error remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem before all I had done is 
1-fixing the warnings about the icons 
2-copy the icons from the image assets to the root of the app

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, what I did to fix was clearing the Plist file, because icons referring it was not not in the project folder.

Hope it helps for someone in future.