# What are the requirements for Apple version on the iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

We have been submitting iOS apps to the App Store with versions like:

```
Version: 1.17
Build: 1.17.45
```

However, it's causes us issues when we have long running features that need to be tested outside of our normal releases. I'd like to put an identifier like:

```
Version: 1.17.0
Build: 1.17.0-FooBar45
```

If I try and submit this it just gives back the error:

```
ERROR ITMS-4236: "Invalid value '1.17.0-FooBar45' for bundle_version" at SoftwareAssets
```

I have also tried the following versions, all with the same error:

- `1.17.0.FooBar45`
- `FooBar45`

The only time it worked was with `1.17.0.45` but that's no better than what we have now.

I cannot find any documentation about what is a "valid version" or if it's just failing because we already have a test flight build with `1.17` in place.

Comment: you must be use higher number that not lower then previous version and make sure that value in number. Characters are not allow

Comment: @NitinGohel But according to the docs, "While developing a new version of your app, you can include a suffix after the number that is being updated; for example 3.1.3a1". I haven't succeeded with that though. Same issue. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102364 for docs.

Comment: Update: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765101/ios-cfbundleversionbuild-number-cant-contain-suffix#comment82491595_47765101

Answer (score 0):

CFBundleVersion has to be a pure version number like 1.21.11 when you want to upload your application to the (iOS) App Store.

You can refer this answer for more clarity : [What's the difference between “version number” in itunes connect, “bundle version”, “bundle version string” in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7281246/4685283)