# iOS CFBundleVersion(Build Number) can't contain suffix?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I tried to use suffix on **CFBundleVersion**(Build Number) in Xcode as the [Apple Developer Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102364) says. But it didn't work.

I've already changed the scheme of Archive to Debug mode (so not in Release mode).

Does anybody know why the rule is different between document and iTunesConnect?

The rule from Apple Developer Document:

[image: [Image] the rule from Apple Developer Document]

The result from Xcode:

[image: [Image] the result from Xcode]

Comment: iTunes Connect has its own requirements. There are plenty of times where you might want to use Xcode for building apps that you do not distribute through iTunes Connect, so there is no reason for them to restrict people from including non-numeric characters in version fields.

Comment: Also it clearly says "When you release the new version of your app, remove the suffix." The build scheme (Debug vs Release) has nothing to do (directly at least) with releasing your app. Uploading the app to iTunes Connect for release to the App Store is what they're talking about there.

Comment: Remember, the `CFBundleVersion` is just a build number. It is not the version the user sees (which is the `CFBundleShortVersionString`). The don't need to be related at all. I start with build 1 and increment by 1 each time I archive.

Comment: @shim Does it means that suffix can only be used locally by building with Xcode.

Comment: No, you can use it however you want. It's just not accepted by iTunes Connect. For example, I used to use enterprise distribution, bypassing iTunes Connect for distribution, so I could use whatever characters I wanted in those fields.

Comment: @maddy Yes, I just wanna add suffix on TestFlight so we can tell what environment we are using directly by the Build number.

Comment: @shim Thanks, it makes sense. But it makes it useless on TestFlight.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that. There are a few options, but what I like to do for that is create a separate target for development builds, giving it its own display name and even a different app icon. All managed in the same Xcode project. That way you can set it up with its own configuration/scheme/build settings and manage it independently of your release version. Only downside is it can increase compilation times. Otherwise you can make notes about the environment in the "what to test" field on Testflight. Or you can come up with your own numeric code e.g. odd numbers are debug builds etc

Comment: Thanks for sharing experience, the way we are using now is to update Test Information on the TestFlight page. Could you let me know how do you know that? Is there any document of Apple talking about this?

Comment: How I know what?