# What is the correct way of versioning in Xcode projects or frameworks

Tags: xcode

I got a little confused about versioning my projects in Xcode, I can see an option from `Targets > General > Version` also another versioning method in `Targets > Info > Bundle version string (short)` so I really get confused why would we need both there? and it can be an issue if we forgot one of them to update, so which one is telling my project/framework version and why these 2 exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between "version number" in iTunes Connect, "bundle version", "bundle version string" in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281085/whats-the-difference-between-version-number-in-itunes-connect-bundle-versio)

Comment: After reading that link, they must be the same version and same thing, so why we need 2 or 3 deferent property's for reflecting same thing?

Comment: To simplify - one (the short one) is the version visible to users, e.g. `1.2.0`, the other one (the long one) is your internal version, usually a build number, e.g. `1020`. Together they form the real version, e.g. `1.2.0-1020`.

Comment: Thanks for help.